# Fetching Column with table name alias is not working in VBA

Tags: oracle, vba, excel

I am trying to connect to Oracle table through VBA and fetching data. My situation is to reference one table multiple times to do pivot. But while running query via VBA it's throwing an error as I am fetching data through table alias: Below is a dummy code.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim strDataSource, strUsername, strPassword, strConnectionString, strquery As String
    Dim objADODBConnection, objADODBRecordset As Object
        strDataSource = "xxxx"
        strUsername = "xxxx"
        strPassword = "xxxx"

        strConnectionString = "Provider=MSDAORA;Data Source=" & strDataSource & ";Persist Security Info=True;Password=" & strPassword & ";User ID=" & strUsername
        Set objADODBConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

        objADODBConnection.Open strConnectionString
        Set objADODBRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

        strquery = "SELECT T1.Column1 FROM Table1 AS T1 WHERE Column2='XXXX' AND Column3='XXXX'"

        Set objADODBRecordset = objADODBConnection.Execute(strquery)

        MsgBox objADODBRecordset.Fields(0).Value

        objADODBRecordset.Close
        objADODBConnection.Close
        Set objADODBRecordset = Nothing
        Set objADODBConnection = Nothing

End Sub
```

The same query is running fine without table alias. Please suggest!!

Comment: Please tell us what error you are getting and what line is the error coming from.

Comment: Does it help if you include `T1.Column2 = 'XXXX' AND T1.Column3 = 'XXXX'`?

Comment: Nope it won't help. As per my understanding if we are using something like "T1. Column2" in VBA then, T1 has to be an object because dot [.] operator only works with an object.

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM Table1 AS T1
```

You should remove 'AS' in from condition -

```
FROM Table1 T1
```

Comment: It worked !!! Thank you
Could you please give me a reason why the Keyword AS creating an issue. 
The query is being thrown to Oracle Client so it should have worked.

Comment: Oracle syntax doesn't required "AS" for the table alias, but in from expression "AS" is part of  flashback query clause ("AS OF") - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#i2126863